# Connection Reset while Transfering files over FTPS using java

Tags: java, ftps

I am using Java(Zehon) to transfer files over FTPS. This is my code snippet.

```
try {
FTPsClient ftpClient = new FTPsClient(host, port,username ,password ,false,keyStorePath,keyStorePass);
ftpClient.sendFile(absFilePath, ftpsFolder);
}catch (FileTransferException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I have telnet the host ip and i am getting connected. I am quite sure that the credentials i am passing is correct.The exception am getting is `com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`
Any suggestions as to what else i may need to add while connecting to the host because the javadoc for FTPsClient does not show any more methods to connect to the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with configuring the keystore file. This is how you actually need to make it:
Download OPENSSL and type this command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in  /path/to/YourVeriSignSSLCert.crt -inkey /path/to/YourPrivateKey.key -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile /path/to/YourIntermediateCertificate.cer -caname root
```

YourVeriSignSSLCert.crt is your current openssl certificate

YourPrivateKey.key is your current private key

YourIntermediateCertificate.cer is the VeriSign Intermediate CA

The exported keystore will be in 'mycert.p12'

Now the keystore file is of pkcs12 format i am converting this into jks format :

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -trustcacerts -srckeystore mycert.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore md_keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Now this is the keystore file that needs to be passed to the program.

Comment: Hope dis helps any1 else facing the same problem :)

Comment: PKCS12 format is indeed recognized by Java. That's what `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` is for.

Comment: But how can i use this in the program i have mentioned above? I need to pass a String keyStorePath. How can i programattically change the keystore type ?

Comment: See the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SupportClasses) for constructing custom SSLContexts. You have to construct a `KeyManager`, load it from a `KeyStore`, which you construct to be of PKCS12 type, and initialize the `SSLContext` with it.